# Swap 2D int array elements according to user input using printf and scanf

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d, swap

How do i swap the elements in a 2D int array according to use input? For example i have a 2x2 matrix with elements

```
int c[2][2]=
{
  {1,2, },
  {3,4, }
};
```

the user inputs which area to swap like: c[0][0] and c[0][1] then display the new results. Thanks

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void swap(int c[2][2],int &x1,int &y1,int &x2,int &y2)
 {
  int temp = c[x1][y1];
    c[x1][y1] = c[x2][y2];
    c[x2][y2] = temp;
}
int main(void)
{
    int c[2][2]=
     {
      {1,2, },
      {3,4, }
      };
    int x,y;
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5;
    for(x=0;x<2;x++)
    {
    for(y=0;y<2;y++)
    {
     printf("\t%d",c[x][y]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     }

    printf("\nEnter 1st value to be swapped:\n");
    printf("Row\n");
    scanf("%d",&x3);
    printf("Column\n");
    scanf("%d",&y3);
    printf("\nEnter 2nd value to be swapped:\n");
    printf("Row\n");
    scanf("%d",&x4);
    printf("Column\n");
    scanf("%d",&y4);
    if((x3==1&&y3==1)&&(x4==1&&y4==2))
    {
     swap(c[0][0],c[0][1]);
     }
    for(x=0;x<2;x++)
    {
    for(y=0;y<2;y++)
    {
     printf("\t%d",c[x][y]);
     }
     printf("\n");
     }

    system("pause");
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's an easy program, but at first you should write your own code and then ask us your issues, we will not do your home works entirly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to do this:

```
swap(c[x3-1][y3-1],c[x4-1][y4-1]);
```

But before you do that, you'll need to sanitise the variables to ensure they are within the range of the array.